# Reliable 2018 statistics study/report on WildFly version usage in 2018/2019

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

2017 [stats](https://jelastic.com/blog/java-stacks-usage-statistics-2017/) report (Jelastic cloud) says that WildFly 8 is most used while WildFly 10 is only 8.8% adopted.

But as of today latest available version is 16.

What is the situation around now? I don't think WildFly 10 and newer is not around that much.

P.S. **My question is not about opinion - I seek a quote to some study/report which is not opinion by definition.**

Answer (score 1):

WildFly 16 support is in progress and its availability is expected since early April, 19. As for the report you're referring to, we've published [Stack Statistics](https://jelastic.com/blog/software-stack-statistics-key-takeaways-2018/) at the end of 2018, but WildFly was not so popular as other. 
Based on our stats, WildFly 10 is the most popular version among WildFly Jelastic users for now and 10+ are 90% of the overall WildFly versions.